# A fallback for Bootstrap's collapse behaviour when JS disabled

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have something exactly [like this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse). It works as show and expected.

However, when JavaScript is disabled, the button doesn't work. What is the easiest fall back I can put in place to overcome this?

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
    <h2>Hello, how are you?</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created [this codepen](http://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/EVZMXB), but not sure why the collapse doesn't work (I'm new to Codepen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without JS you can't use the collapse function, you therefore have to manually show the .collapse content by default.

In my opinion you have two options:

1.) Detect if JS is activated (e.g. with [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)) and make a special statement in your css. e.g. `.no-js .collapse { display: block}`

2.) Make use of the noScript HTML tag, which only loads if JS is disabled. Put it at the beginning of your document

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        .collapse {
            display: block;
        }
              </style>
            </noscript>
```

(3. You could set the default css to `.collapse { display: block; }` and change it via javascript on page load. But I guess this would be a bit over the top..)

Comment: That works beautifully. By the way, why couldn't I get the collapse to work in my Codpen?

Comment: @Ciwan Did you include jQuery? I recommend using bootply for bootstrap related fiddles..

Answer (score 2):

I was racking my brain for how to do this, but then I discovered that:

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">`

gets expanded by adding `"show"` to the class list.

So my solution:

1. Have the navs expanded by default.
2. Have the navs be a row instead of column, with space around them.
3. Have the toggle button hidden by default.
4. Hide the nav, make the navs a centered column, and show the toggle button using JS (if available).

HTML

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end show" id="navbarSupportedContent">`

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
  a.nav-link {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: space-around;
  }
  button.navbar-toggler {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

EDIT: (now working properly using JS's `window.matchMedia` API)

JS (jQuery - could easily be done with Vanilla JS though)

```
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 990px)");

if (mq.matches) {
  // change back to centered columns
  $('.navbar-nav').css({'flex-direction': 'column', 'justify-content': 
'center'});
  // show toggle button
  $('button.navbar-toggler').css('opacity', '1.0');
  // collapse
  $('.collapse.show').removeClass('show');
}
```